# how to get share count on graph api 2.10

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the previous graph api version 2.7 this was working for all count (total, like, comment):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/?fields=id,share,og_object{engagement{count},likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.limit(0).summary(true)}&id=<ad_url>&access_token=<access_token>
```

But In graph api new version 2.10 share is depricated.

Can any one help me to get the share count in graph api new version 2.10.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/url

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the query

```
https://graph.facebook.com?id=<your-url>&fields=og_object{engagement}
```

The answer will be

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "engagement": {
      "count": 197,
      "social_sentence": "197 people like this."
    },
    "id": "895062470590407"
  },
  "id": "<your-url>"
}
```

`og_object->engagement->count` total shares here

Comment: Hi @Anton thanks for the answare, do you know to the limit for this api, I mean to say how much request I hit on this api?

Comment: unfortunately it looks like this solution is no longer working. I'm curious if you know an alternative.

Comment: Check my answer for this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55773433/8495047

Answer (score 2):

For all engagement share, like, comments use this query.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=id,share,og_object{engagement{count},likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.limit(0).summary(true)}&id=<url>
```

Output:

```
{
   "id": <url>,
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 61
   },
   "og_object": {
      "engagement": {
         "count": 61
      },
      "likes": {
         "data": [

         ],
         "summary": {
            "total_count": 0,
            "can_like": false,
            "has_liked": false
         }
      },
      "comments": {
         "data": [

         ],
         "summary": {
            "order": "chronological",
            "total_count": 0,
            "can_comment": false
         }
      },
      "id": "975365752527984"
   }
}
```