# Facebook engagement count without token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to be able to get engagement statistics on facebook for any url by using the facebook graph api. Unfortunately since 2 days ago (Sep 23 2020), the API returns an error. It says it is transient, but it doesn't seem to be true. Instead it seems to reject the request because no access token is given.

Is there an alternative to get engagement numbers without creating an app and using a token?

```
$ curl -g 'http://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{engagement}&ids=http://lwn.net'
{"error":{"message":"(#2) Service temporarily unavailable","type":"OAuthException","is_transient":true,"code":2,"fbtrace_id":"..."}}
```

This way to query the facebook graph api was documented in those two questions:

- [API Share count Facebook Graph deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761103/api-share-count-facebook-graph-deprecated)
- [how to get share count on graph api 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613727/how-to-get-share-count-on-graph-api-2-10/45796935)

Comment: No, there is no alternative. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/url states that this _needs_ an access token.

Comment: It used to state that without being really required. So maybe there's hope?

Comment: Section “Query String Parameters” says “access_token - Required”, so more likely not.